# Data range using Between in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to select data in different ranges for a category using IN but not quite sure the syntax
ex: a category has the number 1,3,4 then 20 to 30, then 100 to 110

I use the syntax

```
Case category = 
    When categoryId IN (1,3,4, [20-30],[100-110] Then 'Running'
```

But I received syntax error. How do I do it?

Comment: have you considered reading books online? or maybe consulting a basic tutorial on SQL syntax?

Comment: Where is END for CASE statement

Comment: I have tried reading a few on line but could not get anything like my question

Comment: You are missing  ) before Then 'Running' and END after Then 'Running'

Comment: @Rajesh - That is only one of the problems...

Comment: sorry I just want to get to the point but i know the case must have END statement. My problem is IN (...) how do I specify different data range in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
SELECT
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   (VALUES(1,1),
                                    (3,4),
                                    (20,30),
                                    (100,110)) Ranges(Low, High)
                      WHERE  categoryId BETWEEN Low AND High) THEN 'Running'
       END
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE 
   WHEN categoryId IN (1,3,4) OR 
        (categoryId >= 20 AND categoryId <= 30) OR 
        (categoryId >= 100 AND categoryId <= 110) 
   THEN 'Running' 
END
```

Comment: Thank you this is the simplest solution I like

Comment: @user3539797 Thanks, don't forget to accept the answer if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple scalar function as i normally do .

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Categoory_Range] (@CategoryID as bigInt)  
RETURNS bit AS  
BEGIN 
Declare @result as bit = 0


    -- Need to tack a delimiter onto the end of the input string if one doesn't exist
    if(@CategoryID <= 4 and @CategoryID > 0)
       begin
         set @result =  1
       end
     else if(@CategoryID >20 and @CategoryID <= 30)
       begin
          set @result =1
     end
     else if(@CategoryID > 100 and @CategoryID <= 110)
        begin
         set @result = 1
         end
     else 
     begin
         set @result= 0
      end 

   return @result


END
```

When and where ever you want to use like

```
Select
  Case WHEN [Categoory_Range](CategoryID) > 0 Then  'Running' ELSE 'Whatever' END FROM MyTable.
```

I love using the functions for you don't have to rewrite this all the time. I normally do it with functions. Check the function above didn't test though. Hope it helps. However if you just want to write it once, you can just want to write once, you can do in the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
CASE
   WHEN CategoryId in (1,3,4) or
   (CategoryId between 20 and 30) or
   (CategoryId between 100 and 110) THEN 'Running'
END
```